# How to use both DataSource and DataSourceID in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

work on C# asp.net vs05.i need to save some value and show them on the **gridview**.So under the button event i write a code that save value ,and show on gridview.I can save value but problem occur when show on gridview.So i use the **DataSource** .I also set the `GridviewTask-->Choose Data Source--> DataSourceID` ,because user  need to edit information set on the page. after use the DataSourceID show this error message : 
**Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView2'.  Remove one definition.**

How can i use the both in one grid view?if i can not? then how to give user this facility that they can edit information set on the grid with out use any other contorl.

Comment: you asked 32 question and not mark even 1 answer?

Comment: **32 questions and not a single one accepted!!** Gotta be a new record on Stackoverflow!!

Answer (score 3):

**You cannot** - either use DataSource or DataSourceID - but you can't use both at the same time.

From your question, it's not quite clear **why** you'd want to use both at the same time. What is it exactly that you're trying to accomplish?? Please clarify.

Marc